# fastboot usage example explained?

Tags: ember.js

Can some one please explain in more detail how the example posted in [the "Fastboot" readme file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastboot#usage) would work, as to where in an existing Ember application this would be integrated? Thanks.

This is a copy of the code I don't understand:

```js
// Usage
const FastBoot = require('fastboot');
 
let app = new FastBoot({
  distPath: 'path/to/dist'
});
 
app.visit('/photos')
  .then(result => result.html())
  .then(html => res.send(html));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link that should help: https://www.ember-fastboot.com/quickstart
The main idea, from what I read is. Using Fastboot give you a choice of 'running your code' on your local server(browser) or server(web). Using Fastboot you don't have to alter your environment for the  code to work. Your code remain the same(just write code), your environment that your code run in is what changes. Hope that helps.